# Laravel API resource returning all the value of the model

Tags: php, laravel, api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfLt0.jpg)I have a 'Portfolio' model. I made a resource controller for it and named it 'PortfolioRsource'. Inside this resource controller I have returned this

```
return [
    'name' => $this->brand_name,
];
```

Inside a controller I'm returning this

```
return $portfolios =  PortfoliResource::collection(Portfolio::all());
```

Which gives me a array like the picture

[picture of the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfLt0.jpg)
That's fine but when I use the dd() function, all the fields belongs to the 'Portfolio' more are present there.

[pic of dd($portfolios)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC6KZ.jpg)

And when I send the '$portfolios' variable to any 'blade' file I can access to any field.
I dont want that, I wanna return specific fields only. What would be the solution.

Comment: Resources are used for APIs. Your approach is wrong.

Comment: try `PortfoliResource::collection(Portfolio::select('your','columns')->all());`

Answer (score -1):

Check this use `get()` method

```
$portfoli=Portfolio::select('column_name','column_name')->get();
```

Now pass it through your blade by using compact

```
return view('your_blade',compact('portfoli'));
```

Comment: Its not working.
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()